# Taxonomy based file path for imce

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities, files

I've added the field "field_sdb_profile_basics_forv" to my (default) drupal user profile.

Now I need the IMCE editor to detect and choose the file path, based on that field specifically.

As pr project limitations, I can not:

- Add additional modules for functionality (For example Profiles2)
  Alter core and or Module code.

Basically, I need to find a way to make a one line request for the Directory path

I am imagening it will be something like this, but can't seem to get the syntax right:

```
return $user->field_sdb_profile_basics_forv['und'][0]['value'];
```